# How can I easily see which of my followed games have been fully released?

Tags: steam

I've added a lot of early access and unreleased games to my list of followed games on steam.

I would like to know which of these have now been fully released. Is there an easier way to do so other than going trough the list one by one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this with followed games.  But if you add the games to your wishlist, you can exclude unreleased and early access games from displaying on [your wishlist page](https://store.steampowered.com/wishlist):

[image: Exclude early access]

You can also sort by release date to see which have most recently been released:

[image: sort by release date]

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work... Early Access games have release dates too, but they get updated to the date of the "1.0" release by the looks of it.  Take [Factorio](https://store.steampowered.com/app/427520/Factorio/) as an example, it's release date is August 14, 2020, but I know for sure that game was around way before that.  [Wayback](https://web.archive.org/web/20170429032726/https://store.steampowered.com/app/427520/Factorio/) shows it once had a release date of February 25, 2016.

Comment: @TimmyJim: See update